# How reference all return type of list function to compose react hoc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I want to create a compose function. It combine list of higher order components and last param is original component with props which has intersaction all return types.

Let me show the source code because my explanation is a bit confusing(sorry for that)

1. Util function to create a HOC

```typescript
function createHOC<TProps, TInjectedKeys extends keyof TProps>(
  hookFn: (props: any) => Pick<TProps, TInjectedKeys>,
  displayName: string
) {
  return function hoc(Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>) {
    const UiHOC = (props1: Omit<TProps, TInjectedKeys>) => {
      const hookData = hookFn({ ...props1 });

      return <Component {...(props1 as TProps)} {...hookData} />;
    };

    const oriDisplayName = Component.displayName || Component.name || '';
    UiHOC.displayName = `${displayName}(${oriDisplayName})`;

    return UiHOC;
  };
}
```

so i will create 2 new hocs:

```typescript
const uiHOC1 = createHOC(() => ({ a: '1' }), 'uiHOC1');
const uiHOC2 = createHOC(() => ({ b: 2, c: false }), 'uiHOC2');
```

2. My compose function with reference type

```typescript
type HOCType<TProps, TInjectedKeys extends keyof TProps> = (
  Component: React.ComponentType<any>
) => React.ComponentType<Omit<TProps, TInjectedKeys>>;

type PropsType<HOCFns> = HOCFns extends HOCType<infer P, never>[] ? P : never;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

function compose<Fns extends HOCType<any, any>[]>(
  ...objs: [...Fns]
): (component: React.ComponentType<UnionToIntersection<PropsType<Fns>>>) => any;

function compose(): any {
// ...
}
```

3. I want to get reference type in component declaration.

```typescript
const ComponentWithHOCs = compose(
  uiHOC1,
  uiHOC2
)((props: I_NEED_REFER_TYPE_HERE) => {
  // It must not be reported typing error here
  return <>{props.a}</>;
});
```

It is working but im not sure it correct. Help me to confirm or show me if i wrong.
Here is Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-bush-ezyx6?file=/src/App.tsx
Thanks